# SwiftUI TextFields with Integer

Tags: xcode, swiftui, integer

In SwiftUI, I have two textfields. One of them is String and the other should be Int. And I want textfields to appear empty before and after "save" functionality.

this is how I declare my Int variable

```
@State private var newItemDays: Int?
```

this is the textfields

```
TextField("Task Title", text: $newItemTitle)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.white)
                    
TextField("Days to Countdown", value: $newItemDays, formatter: NumberFormatter())
                        .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.white)
```

And my Ok button saves them.

```
 Button("OK") {
                            if let days = newItemDays {
                                
                                let newItem = CountdownItem(title: newItemTitle, daysLeft: days)
                                self.store.add(item: newItem)
                                newItemTitle = ""
                                newItemDays = 0
                                isTextFieldVisible = false
                            }
                            
                        }
```

If statement always return false even though I put integer there. If I remove optional from the declaration and make it equal to 0, it works but this time I see 0 at the textfields (it should appear empty)

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom `NumberFormatter` & set the [`zeroSymbol`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter/1410405-zerosymbol) to be an empty `String`:

```
let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.zeroSymbol = ""
    return formatter
}()
```

And your `TextField` becomes:

```
TextField("Days to Countdown", value: $newItemDays, formatter: formatter)
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I dont see 0. But after I save it, I cant clean textfield (with the formatter one), even though I put newItemDays = 0 afterwards. Is it anything to do with the formatter?

Comment: This was such a pain, I was using sheet which kept the old values, even though I was giving them new values. Then I used onDismiss for sheet and updated the value there. And it worked. wanted to write it for anyone with the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

Use `format:` instead of `formatter:`

```
TextField("Days to Countdown", value: $newItemDays, format: .number)
```

When `value` is `Int?` it will appear empty initially.

By the way, you shouldn't init objects like `NumberFormatter()` inside `body` it is a memory leak, best stick to value types.